# Borel-/Laplace-transform and $\psi$-function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, laplace-transform

I'm considering some family of functions whose coefficients of their power series occur in the columns of the following matrix **A** *(of course thought as of infinite size)*

$ \qquad $ [image: picture]

The second of that functions is 
$$ \small f_1(x) = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta(1-k) x^k \tag{1.1}$$
By evaluating it numerically for various $x$ using Noerlund sums I arrived at the guessed closed-form expression for it as
$$ \small f_1(x) = \log(1/x) - \psi(1/x) \tag{1.2}$$

- Sanity-check: if I feed the following in W/A
  $$ \small \text{series [ log(t) - digamma(t) ]} $$
  I get the same series, however in the form for some leading coefficients from which I conclude 
  $$ \small [f_1(1/t) =]  \sum_{k=1}^\infty -\zeta(1-k) \frac 1{t^k} \qquad \qquad \text{ expansion at } t=\infty$$
  so it appears that the guessed closed-form is correct.

---

I have now the next function 
$$ \small f_2(x) =  \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_{k,2} x^k \tag {2.1} $$
where the compositions of the $a_{k,2}$ is of $\zeta()$-values in a a bit more complicated form than the above, but with some describable pattern. However, on searching for a closed form for this I'm stuck.

---

To understand the pattern in the $a_{k,2}$ (and also that of $a_{k,3}$ in the fourth column and so on) I've found a very elegant solution, but I can't do the final step to get the closed forms. To describe that functions I involve Borel- or Laplace-transformation and -reversion.

The Borel-transformation of the series representation of $f_1(x)$ is
$$ \small F_1(x) = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta(1-k) {x^k \over k! } \tag{3.1} $$
and this has a closed form
$$ \small F_1(x) = \log( {\exp(x)-1\over x}) \tag{3.2}$$
Now the "elegant moment" is, that the Borel-transformation of the series representation of $f_2(x)$ 
$$ \small F_2(x) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_{k,2} \frac {x^k}{k!} \tag {3.3} $$
has simply the closed form $$ F_2(x) = (F_1(x))^2 \tag{3.3}$$ and moreover, for all following $c>2$ it is $$ F_c(x) = (F_1(x))^k \tag{3.4} $$

The problem is now that I don't know how to find from this the closed form for $f_2(x)$ (or $f_k(x)$ for higher $k$ by the inverse Borel-transform. W/A helped for $F_1(x)$ but not for the $F_c(x)$ with higher column-index $c$.

> ***Q1:*** What is the closed form for $f_2(x)$ and that of the following members of that family of functions?

---

Additional remark: I'm not experienced with Borel- or Laplace-transform. But while Pari/GP has a function *"serlaplace()"* and this gives the expected transformation from $F_c(x)$ to $f_c(x)$ and I could experiment with this a bit, W/A gives another thing when called *"laplacetransform()"* , actually it gave $f_1(x)/x$ instead $f_1(x)$. So question 2:

> ***Q2:*** What is the correct expression for the series-forward&backward transformations: Borel? Laplace?

*P.s.: I'm not good with tagging of questions like this. Please don't hesitate to improve the tagging if not optimal*